# Jquery delete row and add new row changes with values

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a new row in table using jquery. I can remove rows, and reset the numbering for the table rows and IDs. After that, I am attempt to add new row again with new values and it doesn't work well. The deleted rows that had an id like ID = 3, 4, 5 were replaced with new added rows. The row numbering works but the values do not display. instead values are shown as 'undefined'.

Here is a screenshot of my table showing the values 'undefined'.

[Screenshot1 - table showing 'undefined' values for second attempt of adding new rows with values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtmHr.png)

This is my code for add new row. Row adds well first time. then after delete the new added rows' values show undefined.

```
$('#frmVariantEntry').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        alert('save');

        var count_ModalRows = $('#tbl_variant tbody tr').length;
        alert('Modal table rows are: '+ count_ModalRows);

        var count_variantList = $("#tbl_variantList tbody tr").length;
        alert('table variant list row count is: ' + count_variantList);
            
        var tbody='';


        for (var i = 1; i <= count_ModalRows; i++) {
            
            var row_num = i + count_variantList;
            alert(row_num);

            var attribute = $("#tbl_variant tbody tr").find('input[id^="attribute_id'+row_num+'"]').val();

            var attribute_check = '$("#tbl_variant tbody tr").find("input[id^="attribute_id'+row_num+'"]").val()';
            var id = $('input[id^="attribute_id'+row_num+'"]').attr('id');
            var row_data = $("#tbl_variant tbody").find('tr').text();
            
            var price_field = '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" name="var_price" id="var_price'+(row_num)+'" aria-describedby="helpId">';
            var cost_field = '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" name="var_cost" id="var_cost'+(row_num)+'" aria-describedby="helpId">';
            var delete_row = '<button class="btn btn-danger remove_variant" id="del_variant'+row_num+'" type="button">'+
                                    '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>'+
                                '</button>';

            console.log("ID = " + id + " and attribute = " + attribute);
            console.log("attribute check ID = " + attribute_check);
            console.log("row data = " + row_data);
            console.log("row num = " + row_num);

//-------------- ROWS FORMAT TO ADD TO TABLE -------------------------------------
            tbody +=  "<tr class='var_rows' id='varListID_"+ row_num + "'> \
                        <td>" + row_num +" </td> \
                        <td><span>"+ row_num + "</span> " + attribute +"</td> \
                        <td><span>"+ row_num + "</span> - <span id='values"+row_num+"' class='options'>" + values +"</span></td> \
                        <td>"+ row_num + price_field+"</td> \
                        <td>"+ row_num + cost_field+"</td> \
                        <td class='text-center'>"+delete_row+"</td> \
                    </tr>";

        };
        
        jQuery("#tbl_variantList tbody").append(tbody);
        $("#frmVariantEntry")[0].reset();
        $("#tbl_variant tbody .rows").remove();
        $("#variantModal").modal('hide');
      
    });
```

This is my delete row code:

```
function reset_numbering2() {
        var num = 1;
        // loop through all the counters
        $("#tbl_variantList tbody tr").each(function() {
            
            $(this).attr("id","varListID_"+num);
            $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text(num); //set new count to first column
            $(this).find("td:eq(1) > span").text(num); // set the count of attribute id
            $(this).find("td:eq(1) > span.attribute").attr("id","attribute_id"+num); // set the count value of attribute id
            
            $(this).find("td:eq(2) > span").text(num); //set new count to span
            $(this).find("td:eq(2) > span.options").attr("id","value"+num); // set the count of values id

            $(this).find("button.remove_variant").attr("id", "del_variant" + num); //set id

            num++; //increment count
        })
    }

    $("#tbl_variantList tbody").on("click", ".remove_variant", function (event) {
        
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        reset_numbering2();

        // check log to see if row is deleted
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each(
            function (i) {
              console.log($(this).text());
        });


    });
```

Can someone help me fix this please?

Comment: tip: remove all the ID= and all the calculations/recalculations regarding dynamically generated IDs.  Then see what problems you *thought* dynamic IDs were solving and solve them properly.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have tried this, but cannot work. The select2 data values need to be having different IDs to enable dynamic row creation. I need the input and select2 values with their ID and generated number from a different table and add to this table as new rows dynamically.

Comment: That makes no sense - you take a value from a different table then give it (effectively) a random ID on this table?  There's better ways to link elements, such as using `data-id=` attributes - auto-generated IDs are never a good solution and trying to keep them in sequence is an even worse solution.

Comment: @freedomn-m maybe you are right, i have been stuck on this for the past 10 days. It is a nightmare. please share your thoughts to help me fix this as i am learning jquery, and not exactly a good developer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here goes...

### I. Use `let` instead of `var`.

This will save you a lot of trouble later...

> Variables declared by let are only available inside the block where they're defined

I know you're a noob, so that may not mean much, but just take that as "This will make your life better in the long run"

---

### II. Use string literals

NO: `row.find('input[id^="attribute_id'+row_num+'"]')`

YES:

```
row.find(`input[id^="attribute_id${row_num}"]`)
```

---

### III. Long variable names are at the expense of readability

```
var attribute = row.find('input[id^="attribute_id'+row_num+'"]').val(); // NO
let attr      = row.find(`input[id^="attribute_id${row_num}"]`) //YES
```

---

### IV. Readability will save you

Line up the equals signs of different sections. It will show you what parts are related. The more easily you can read it now means the more easily you will read it later.

---

### V. Use [iterative methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#iterative_methods) for looping through arrays

```
for (var i = 1; i <= count_ModalRows; i++) { // NO
$('#tbl_variant tbody tr').map( (i,row) => { // YES
```

So then, your loop becomes way less complicated:

```
let rows  = $('#tbl_variant tbody tr')

let tbody = rows.map( (i,row) => {


  // Variables
  let row_num  = i + count_variantList;
  let aid1     = `attribute_id${row_num}`
  let inp      = $(`input[id^="attribute_id${aid1}"]`)
  let rowId    = row.attr('id')
  let attC     = row.val();
  let attr     = inp.val();
  let iid      = inp.attr('id');
  let row_data = row.text();
        

  // Price
  let price       = `
    <input 
      type        = "text" 
      class       = "form-control" 
      placeholder = "0.00" 
      name        = "var_price" 
      id          = "var_price${row_num}" 
    >
 `;

  // Cost
  let cost        = `
    <input 
      type        = "text" 
      class       = "form-control" 
      placeholder = "0.00" 
      name        = "var_cost" 
      id          = "var_cost${row_num}" 
    >
  `;

  // Delete Button
  let del         = `
    <button 
      class       = "btn btn-danger remove_variant" 
      id          = "del_variant${row_num}" 
      type        = "button"
    >
      '<i class   = "fa fa-trash"></i>
    </button>
  `;


    // Logging
    console.log( {iid} );  // curly braces = better logs = more readable
    console.log( {attr}     );
    console.log( {attC}     );
    console.log( {row_data} );
    console.log( {row_num}  );


    // Table Rows
    return `
      <tr 
       class = 'var_rows' 
       id    = 'varListID_${row_num}'
      >
        <td>${row_num}</td> \
        <td><span>${row_num}</span> ${attr}</td> \
        <td><span>${row_num}</span> - <span id='values${row_num}' class='options'>${???????? values ???????? Where is this defined?}</span></td> \
        <td>${row_num}${price}</td> \
        <td>${row_num}${cost}</td> \
        <td class='text-center'>${del}</td> \
      </tr>
    `;
}).join(' ')


// Per your comment - how to apply the html to the table
$("#tbl_variantList tbody").append(tbody);
$("#frmVariantEntry")[0].reset();
$("#tbl_variant tbody .rows").remove();
$("#variantModal").modal('hide');
```

---

OK, per your comment. I'm glad these steps have made it easier to read your code and find your problem.

You asked:

> What does join do?

`.map()` produces an array of html rows for tbody.

```
let tbody = rows.map( (i,row) =>
```

But its easier to append a string to the table. `.join(' ')` joins the individual row arrays into one string, which can then be appended.

```
$("#tbl_variantList tbody").append(tbody);
```

---

I rewrote the next part to be two loops: one for rows and one for columns. Once you get comfortable with the idea, you may want to consider rewriting the last part in a similar way.

```
function reset_numbering2() {
  let num  = 1;
  let rows = $("#tbl_variantList tbody tr");

  // Row loop
  rows             .each( (ri,row) => {
    row            .attr( "id",`varListID_${i}` );

    // Col Loop
    row.find("td") .each( (ci,col) => {
      if (ci       === 0)
        col.text(  i  )
      if (ci       === 1) {
        col        .find(" > span").text(i);
        col        .find(" > span.attribute").attr("id",`attribute_id${ci}`);
      }
      if (ci       === 2) {
        col        .find(" > span").text(i);
        col        .find(" > span.options").attr("id",`value${ci}`);
      }
    });
    row            .find("button.remove_variant").attr("id", `del_variant${ci}`);
}

$("#tbl_variantList tbody").on("click", ".remove_variant", function (event) {
    
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    reset_numbering2();

    // check log to see if row is deleted
    $(this)
      .closest('tr')
      .find('td')
      .each( (i,td) => {
          console.log(td.text());
      });

});
```

---

Update: I would also suggest not attaching listeners to elements if you can avoid it. Every time an element changes on the screen you may have to re-add the event. It's better to use an onclick attribute with a call

So instead of

```
  // Delete Button
  let del         = `
    <button 
      class       = "btn btn-danger remove_variant" 
      id          = "del_variant${row_num}" 
      type        = "button"
    >
      '<i class   = "fa fa-trash"></i>
    </button>
  `;

...

$("#tbl_variantList tbody").on("click", ".remove_variant",
```

I would recommend:

```
  // Delete Button
  let del         = `
    <button 
      class       = "btn btn-danger remove_variant" 
      id          = "del_variant${row_num}" 
      type        = "button"
      onclick     = "removeVariant(${row_num})"
    >
      '<i class   = "fa fa-trash"></i>
    </button>
  `;

...

function removeVariant(row_num){
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  reset_numbering2();
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you. I have followed your steps and it has considerably made it easier to read and understand. Much of the junk is reduced. First, I am able to understand my mistakes and now know that its during iteration of rows that the issue of undefined value is coming. So trying to figure out how to continue the numbering from the total number of rows in the table. Second, I am trying to understand the join(' ') and how to append the data to the table row. I understand it as a data array, and need to somehow add row to table. I thank you for your input. please show me more so i can learn too :)

Comment: Thank you, I have followed your example. I understand the picture now. However, the code stops working from let tbody = rows.map( (i, row) => {....  upon saving, the page refreshes and no new row is added. i don't know where i am going wrong. I have multiple dynamic rows created on a modal form table with data for attribute name and options. i am trying to add these multiple rows to this table with price and cost as additional field columns. please advice me.

Comment: Yes, I didn't test any of this, since I don't have access to your code base. Are you looking at the console log to see if there's an error?

Comment: I made some changes. But you should create a minimal version in https://playcode.io/, showing the error, then share it here. That way I can see what error you're getting.

Comment: I have made a minimal version in the playcode.io. heres the link: https://playcode.io/1651445

Comment: I had to make it over at codesandbox because playcode only lets you code 8 lines - my fault. https://codesandbox.io/s/variants-y3vwd7

Comment: Hi Travis, I am beat to this logic and don't know way forward. do you have any other approach that you would recommend please? I want to ensure  the user is able to get the desired result safely and securely using jquery and php.

Comment: @MounishNatwarlal Sorry, your question is too large, the subject too vague for me to spend any more time on it. I recommend breaking the problem apart into smaller questions.